# delete duplicate rows with same values (image attached)

Tags: libreoffice

[image]

As you can see in the image, I have columns of 0-350 (more than 3000 of them in the file) and I was trying to get rid of all the duplicated columns that have the values of 0-350. Is there a quick and easy way to figure this out?
I looked up some old threads but those were dealing with duplicated items in one column. I tried using filter function but I was not able to filter them using rows instead of columns. Any thought?
Thanks in advance!
refmac5

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Let's keep track of the order of your columns. Fill the first empty row at the bottom (I assume that's row 37) with 1, 2, 3, etc. We're going to need this later. Don't use a formula -- each cell must have a value. See:

https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Automatically_Calculating_Series][1](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Automatically_Calculating_Series)

[image]

**Step 2**

For this step, I assume row 36 contains the 350's, and that none of the columns you wish to keep have the number 350 in row 36. Based on your image, that seems a reasonable assumption.

- Ctrl + A
- Data > Sort > Options > *Left to right*
- Data > Sort > Sort Criteria > Sort Key 1 > Row 36 (Descending)

[image]

**Step 3**

All of your "0-350" columns are now on the left. Delete them.

[image]

**Step 4**

Put your columns back in their original order.

- Ctrl + A
- Data > Sort > Options > *Left to right*
- Data > Sort > Sort Criteria > Sort Key 1 > Row 37 (Ascending)

[image]

**Step 5**

Delete the last row -- the one we created in Step 1.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a scriptable commandline solution, and the duplicates are in alternate columns as shown in your example, then you could simply take a *slice* of the array of input fields consisting of the first element followed by the second, fourth, and so on. In `perl` (whose arrays are zero-based) that would be indices `0,1,3,...N-1` you could do that as

```
perl -F, -alne 'print join ",", @F[ 0, grep {$_ & 1} 1..$#F ]' data.csv > filtered.csv
```

(the `grep {$_ & 1} 1..$#F` part generates the odd indices).